# Implementation of the UnmarshalYAML Interface for a custom Struct

Tags: go, struct, yaml, unmarshalling

I have the following structs, interfaces, and functions:

```
type FruitBasket struct {
    Capacity int `yaml:"capacity"`
    Fruits []Fruit
}

type Fruit interface {
    GetFruitName() string
}

type Apple struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

func (apple *Apple) GetFruitName() string {
    return apple.Name
}

type tmpFruitBasket []map[string]yaml.Node

func (fruitBasket *FruitBasket) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var tmpFruitBasket tmpFruitBasket

    if err := value.Decode(&tmpFruitBasket); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fruits := make([]Fruit, 0, len(tmpFruitBasket))

    for i := 0; i < len(tmpFruitBasket); i++ {
        for tag, node := range tmpFruitBasket[i] {
            switch tag {
            case "Apple":
                apple := &Apple{}
                if err := node.Decode(apple); err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                fruits = append(fruits, apple)
            default:
                return errors.New("Failed to interpret the fruit of type: \"" + tag + "\"")
            }
        }
    }

    fruitBasket.Fruits = fruits

    return nil
}
```

With this code, I can parse the following yaml File:

```
FruitBasket:
  - Apple:
      name: "apple1"
  - Apple:
      name: "apple2"
```

The main function looks like:

```
func main() {
    data := []byte(`
FruitBasket:
  - Apple:
      name: "apple1"
  - Apple:
      name: "apple2"
`)

    fruitBasket := new(FruitBasket)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, &fruitBasket)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(fruitBasket.Fruits); i++ {
        switch fruit := fruitBasket.Fruits[i].(type) {
        case *Apple:
            fmt.Println("The name of the apple is: " + fruit.GetFruitName())
        }
    }
}
```

However, I CANNOT parse the following yaml string:

```
FruitBasket:
  capacity: 2
  - Apple:
      name: "apple1"
  - Apple:
      name: "apple2"
```

With this string, I get the following error: `error: yaml: did not find expected key`.

How do I have to adjust the implementation of the UnmarshalYAML interface, to also parse the latter string?

Comment: Shouldn't you have capacity as `- capacity: 2` (Add the hyphen)

Comment: If I have capacity as `- capacity: 2`, I will get the error `error: Failed to interpret the fruit of type: "capacity"`.

Comment: Atleast your yaml is correct now. Now the problem remains is with the structs you have declared.

Comment: Can you give me more information about what are exactly the problems with my structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your YAML is invalid. Each YAML value is either a scalar, a sequence or a mapping.

At `capacity:`, the YAML processor decides that this level contains a mapping as it sees the first key. Now, on the next line, it sees `- Apple:`, a sequence item. This is not valid inside a mapping level; it expects the next key instead and therefore gives you an error `did not find expected key`.

A fix of the structure could look like this:

```
FruitBasket:
  capacity: 2
  items:
  - Apple:
      name: "apple1"
  - Apple:
      name: "apple2"
```

Note that the sequence items still appear on the same level, however since `items:` does not have an inline value, the items are parsed as a sequence that is the value of the key `items`. Another key on the same indentation level would end the sequence.

You can then load this into a type like:

```
type tmpFruintBasket struct {
  Capacity int
  Items []map[string]yaml.Node
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer!

I implemented the type as you suggested:

```type tmpFruitBasket struct {
    Capacity int `yaml:“capacity“`
    Items []map[string]yaml.Node `yaml:“,inline“`
}```

However, this does not work, because the „,inline“ flag is not allowed for slices.

Also, when removing the „,inline“ flag, not data is loaded into the type. The data is simply ignored.

When not implementing „Items“ as a sequence, but as a simple map, it works perfectly with the „,inline“ flag.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Well yes, inlining a slice into a struct does not have any meaningful semantics. Without `inline`, it works for me in a [simplistic setup](https://gist.github.com/flyx/a0e40807a0d347c39756b450d375c9a1); can you provide an MVCE of your current solution?

Comment: btw, the YAML way of denoting the type of a value is using *tags* instead of a single key-value pair (e.g. `- !apple\n      name: "apple1"` – that's an actual linebreak followed by necessary indentation). That would simplify the `Items` type to `[]yaml.Node` and each node has a `Tag` field which will be set to `!apple` with this method. Perhaps you want to simplify your code with this?

Comment: You can find my current solution here: https://github.com/Floble/samples/blob/master/fruitbasket/main.go. I will also consider using such tags, but I try to keep the yaml as simple as possible, so non-coders can more easily interpret it.

Comment: In line 79, `Apple` should be `fruits` (go-yaml automatically lower-cases field names) and the inner `Apple:` level is missing.

Comment: I would like to omit the `fruits` tag, but instead specify the concrete fruits, such as apples, strawberries and so on, directly. So, the inner `Apple` tag would not be necessary. Is that possible?

Comment: Well you can have a YAML sequence (mapped to a Go slice) for each fruit type inside `tmpFruitBasket` so that your input is like `{capacity: 2, apples: […], bananas: […]}` and then in `UnmarshalYAML` merge the slices together into the single slice of the final type. I suggest you open a new question with details if you require further assistance.

Comment: I opened a new question with more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636689/go-yaml-custom-unmarshalyaml-interface-for-an-abstract-struct-and-its-implement. Thanks a lot for your help so far!