# Custom UnmarshalYAML interface for an interface and its implementations

Tags: go, struct, yaml, unmarshalling

I implemented an interface `Fruit` and two implementations of it: `Apple` and `Banana`.

Into objects of the two implementations I want to load data from a yaml file:

```
capacity: 4
Apple:
- name: "apple1"
  number: 1
- name: "apple2"
  number: 1
Banana:
- name: "banana1"
  number: 2
```

I implemented the `UnmarshalYaml` interface to load data into my objects:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

type FruitBasket struct {
    Capacity int `yaml:"capacity"`
    Fruits []Fruit
}

func NewFruitBasket() *FruitBasket {
    fb := new(FruitBasket)

    return fb
}

type Fruit interface {
    GetFruitName() string
    GetNumber() int
}

type Apple struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
    Number int `yaml:"number"`
}

type Banana struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
    Number int `yaml:"number"`
}

func (apple *Apple) GetFruitName() string {
    return apple.Name
}

func (apple *Apple) GetNumber() int {
    return apple.Number
}

func (banana *Banana) GetFruitName() string {
    return banana.Name
}

func (banana *Banana) GetNumber() int {
    return banana.Number
}

type tmpFruitBasket struct {
    Capacity int `yaml:"capacity"`
    Fruits []map[string]yaml.Node
}

func (fruitBasket *FruitBasket) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var tmpFruitBasket tmpFruitBasket

    if err := value.Decode(&tmpFruitBasket); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fruitBasket.Capacity = tmpFruitBasket.Capacity

    fruits := make([]Fruit, 0, len(tmpFruitBasket.Fruits))

    for i := 0; i < len(tmpFruitBasket.Fruits); i++ {
        for tag, node := range tmpFruitBasket.Fruits[i] {
            switch tag {
            case "Apple":
                apple := &Apple{}
                if err := node.Decode(apple); err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                fruits = append(fruits, apple)
            case "Banana":
                banana := &Banana{}
                if err := node.Decode(banana); err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                fruits = append(fruits, banana)
            default:
                return errors.New("Failed to interpret the fruit of type: \"" + tag + "\"")
            }
        }
    }

    fruitBasket.Fruits = fruits

    return nil
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`
capacity: 4
Apple:
- name: "apple1"
  number: 1
- name: "apple2"
  number: 1
Banana:
- name: "banana1"
  number: 2
`)

    fruitBasket := NewFruitBasket()

    err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, &fruitBasket)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(fruitBasket.Capacity)

    for i := 0; i < len(fruitBasket.Fruits); i++ {
        switch fruit := fruitBasket.Fruits[i].(type) {
        case *Apple:
            fmt.Println(fruit.Name)
            fmt.Println(fruit.Number)
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is not working. It seems that the data for the `Apple` and `Banana` tags are not loaded. Probably, because of the missing yaml flag for the `Fruits` slice in my `tmpFruitBasket` struct. But, as `Fruit` is an interface, I cannot define a yaml flag. In the future, I want to implement other structs representing concrete fruits (e.g., Strawberry) implementing the interface `Fruit`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Your structs don't match your YML at all. Your YML defines an object with three fields: `capacity` (an int), `Apple` (a list of objects), and `Banana` (a list of objects). Also worth noting there is no such thing as an "abstract struct" in Go; you have an *interface*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intermediate type you need:

```golang
type tmpFruitBasket struct {
  Capacity int
  Apple    []yaml.Node `yaml:"Apple"`
  Banana   []yaml.Node `yaml:"Banana"`
}
```

Then, the loading function will look like:

```golang
// helper to load a list of nodes as a concrete type
func appendFruits(fruits []Fruit, kind reflect.Type, input []yaml.Node) ([]Fruit, error) {
  for i := range input {
    val := reflect.New(kind).Interface()
    if err := input[i].Decode(val); err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
    fruits = append(fruits, val.(Fruit))
  }
  return fruits, nil
}


func (fruitBasket *FruitBasket) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var tmp tmpFruitBasket

    if err := value.Decode(&tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fruitBasket.Capacity = tmp.Capacity

    var fruits []Fruit
    var err error
    // sadly, there is no nicer way to get the reflect.Type of Apple / Banana
    fruits, err = appendFruits(
      fruits, reflect.TypeOf((*Apple)(nil)).Elem(), tmp.Apple)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
    fruits, err = appendFruits(
      fruits, reflect.TypeOf((*Banana)(nil)).Elem(), tmp.Banana)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }

    fruitBasket.Fruits = fruits
    return nil
}
```

**Edit:** If you stick with sorting each type into a dedicated slice, you could of course directly type those as `[]Apple` and `[]Banana` and just merge them. This answer is a continuation of digging into the issue of dynamically loading input to different types, started with your previous questions. Doing this only makes sense if you at some point don't know the static type anymore (e.g. if you provide an API to add additional fruit types at runtime).

Comment: Thx! Works very well! Does go-yaml allow to specify multiple, alternative yaml tags for a variable? If so, the intermediate struct must only include the `Fruit` interface, but not `Apples` and `Bananas`.

Comment: Please don't call them tags, they're *keys*. Tags are the tokens that start with `!`, you're currently not using them. By constructing native values from `yaml.Node`s, you can do almost anything (but you'd need to implement it yourself by interpreting the values in the node). With every one of your questions, I more and more get the feeling that all this is an elaborate [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should write up what you *actually* want to do instead of asking after every answer „well but what if I want to do it differently?“.

Comment: I was just wondering whether there would be another solution to the problem supported by go-yaml from scratch. Anyhow, your answer is a solution to my problem. So, many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Apart from `inline`, go-yaml does not have any structure-altering features out of the box.